# Can I edit a text object while rendering?

Tags: rendering, edit-mode, text-object

I am rendering a text for an intro right now, I am on the 210th frame, is it possible to still edit the text without messing the rendering up or not?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to continue working on your scene while rendering, you just need to click on the image icon in the bottom left corner of the render screen.

[image]

Click on 3D View from the menu to continue editing your scene while the animation renders in the background.

[image]

For the changes you make on your scene to take effect in the final render, you are going to have to re-render your animation.